# Undefined reference to a function using argv[1] to pass filename to other function and read data struct

Tags: c, undefined-reference

I can't solve the error: undefined reference to `lire` in function `main` in `proj.c`.

`collect2: error ld returned 1 exit status`

Question structure

1. Details of question
2. Code for main functions - `allouer` (=allocate) and `lire` (=read) (file is called `allocate_plat.c`)
3. `proj.c` source file - should take filename as argument and read it using function `lire`
4. `proj.h` header file - structure definitions and prototype functions
5. `Makefile` - I can't believe this causes the problem but included for completeness
6. Example txt file to read. For information only

1.This is my first at using multiple source files - the goal is to open a game board for a game like this:  http://www.rci-jeux.com/jeux/labychiffres/laby.swf .

I am studying abroad, and have some trouble in technical discussions with the lecturer, and think my understanding of pointers or at least when and where to use * and & is weak - I have already spent some time trying to get the game file passed from the command line of proj.c to allocate_plat.c - I believe this works, but if you spot a mistake please point it out. Code follows - have had guidance for the structures so am confident they are appropriate.

What I have tried - the current situation is the culmination of a few hours ironing out (I hope) bugs with passing the filename argument from `proj.c` to `allocate_plat.c` This is the first time I have seen this type of error,and I am not sure where to start.

I have read [C++ Undefined reference to function implemented and templated in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144679/c-undefined-reference-to-function-implemented-and-templated-in-code) and can't see the solution.

2.`allocate_plat.c` to allocate space and then read the game data (this is by analogy with a matrix data structure used in a weekly assignment, and we have been told we can largely copy that, so it should work, (though for that I only used one source file.)

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "proj.h"

int allouer(PLATEAU *PLAT, int nl, int nc, int ldep, int cdep, int larr, int carr, int longdem, int sumdem){
    int i,succes;
    PLAT->grille = (int**)calloc(nl,sizeof(int*));
    PLAT->nl = nl;
    PLAT->nc = nc;
    PLAT->longdem = longdem;
    PLAT->sumdem = sumdem;
    PLAT->dep.indl = ldep;
    PLAT->dep.indc = cdep;
    PLAT->arr.indl = larr;
    PLAT->arr.indc = carr;

    succes = (PLAT->grille != NULL);
    for (i=0; succes && i<nl;i++){
    PLAT->grille[i]=(int*)calloc(nc,sizeof(int));
    succes = (PLAT->grille[i] != NULL);
    }
    return succes;
}

int lire(char *nom_fichier, PLATEAU *PLAT){
    int i,j,succes, c;
    PLATEAU jeu;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(nom_fichier, "rt");
    if(fp==NULL) {
        printf("Erreur d'ouverture du fichier\n");
        return 0;
    }
    c = fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&PLAT->nl,&PLAT->nc);//Read first line
    if( c != 2){
        printf("Erreur de format de fichier\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    c = fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&PLAT->dep.indl,&PLAT->dep.indc);//Read second line
    if( c != 2){
        printf("Erreur de format de fichier\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    c = fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&PLAT->arr.indl,&PLAT->arr.indc);//Read third line
    if( c != 2){
        printf("Erreur de format de fichier\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    c = fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&PLAT->longdem,&PLAT->sumdem);//Read fourth line
    if( c != 2){
        printf("Erreur de format de fichier\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }

//ALLOCATE THE FILE TO THE STRUCT
    succes = allouer(PLAT, PLAT->nl, PLAT->nc, PLAT->dep.indl, PLAT->dep.indc, PLAT->arr.indl, PLAT->arr.indc, PLAT->longdem, PLAT->sumdem );
    if(succes==0) {
        printf("Erreur d'allocation\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    for(i=0; i< PLAT->nl; i++){
        for(j=0; j<PLAT->nc; j++){
            c=fscanf(fp, "%d", &PLAT->grille[i][j]);
            if(c != 1){
                printf("Erreur de format de fichier\n");
                fclose(fp);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```

3.Main source file: `proj.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "proj.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
//  char nom_fichier[25];   
int choix, choix2, succes;
PLATEAU jeu;

    if (argc > 1){
    char *nom_fichier = argv[1];
        lire(nom_fichier, &jeu);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

4.My header file: `proj.h`

```
#pragma once
typedef struct position_st{//position st is tag for the type: "struct posiition_st"
    int indl;//indice of ligne
    int indc;//indice of colonne
    }POSITION;

typedef struct element_st{
    POSITION valeur;
    struct element_st *P_suivant;
    }ELEMENT;

typedef struct pile_st{
    ELEMENT * P_sommet;
    } PILE;

//##########PLATEAU STRUCTURE DEFINITION##############
typedef struct plat_st{
//########## INFORMATION INCLUDED IN THE GAME FILES ###################
    POSITION dep;//start position
    POSITION arr;//finishing position
    int longdem;//length of path requested
    int sumdem;//total demanded
    int nl;//number of rows in grille
    int nc;//number of columns in grille
    int ** grille;//Playing table
//########## PART TO DO WITH THE CURRENT GAME ###################
    int longcur;//current length
    int sumcur;//current total
    PILE chemin;//the path
    }PLATEAU;
//########## FUNCTION PROTOTYPES ########################
//allouer allocates the variables for the game
int allouer(PLATEAU *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int);

//lire reads a game from a file
int lire(char *, PLATEAU *);
```

5.My `makefile`:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I #-Wall
DEPS = proj.h
OBJ = proj.o allocate_plat.o

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

proj: $(OBJ)
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

6.Example of the file structure (probably not needed comments would not be in it)

```
4 4// number of orws and columns in board
1 1//starting coordinates (based at 1)
4 4//ending coordinates (based at 1)
11 96//path length and sum of elements of path required
10 13 2 5//board grid
3 15 9 4
8 6 11 14
7 12 1 16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the Makefile. With

```
CFLAGS = -I #-Wall
```

later

```
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

will become

```
gcc -I -c -o proj.o proj.c
```

...where `-c` is interpreted as a directory (argument to `-I`). Did you mean

```
CFLAGS = -I . #-Wall
```

?

Comment: Awesome thanks - I really didn't think that was where the problem was, but it now compiles with no errors. Will tick when I can...